# Proving $\mathbb{Z}_p[x]$ has Unique Factorization.

Tags: abstract-algebra, number-theory, elementary-number-theory, polynomials, ring-theory

I'm self-learning some number theory. I'm trying to prove or disprove the following:

$$\mathbb{Z}_p[x]\text{ has a Unique Factorization Theorem}$$ (where $p$ is some rational prime)

1. Consider some $f \in \mathbb{Z}_p[x]$.
2. Obviously, $\nexists g\in\mathbb{Z}_p[x]$ such that $g\mid f$

It seems to me that it follows that there is no UFT for this ring. However, 2) is pretty ambigious.

Comment: Is $\mathbb Z_p$ integers modulo $p$ or $p$-adic integers?

Comment: 2) Undermeans that $g$ isn't constant or $f$

Comment: Integers modulo $p$, where $p$ is some prime.

Comment: rings of polynomials with coefficients in a field are UFDs

Comment: It's difficult to figure out what your confusion is.Why do you think there would be no such polynomial $g$ (in general) for some $f$? Why would that be in violation of unique factorization? For all we know $f$ could be irreducible (a prime, if you wish).

Comment: Compare: in the ring of integers $6$ is not a prime because it is a product of smaller integers, but $3$ is not such a product, and hence a prime. In $\Bbb{Z}_2[x]$ we have $x^2+1=(x+1)^2$, so $x^2+1$ is not a prime, but $x^2+x+1$ is. But we haven't really touched uniqueness of factorization yet. That fails in $\Bbb{Z}_{12}[x]$, because $x^2-1=(x-1)(x+1)$ and also $x^2-1=(x-5)(x+5)$ so here factorization is not unique (it's a bit delicate when there are zero divisors, but let's ignore that). But, $12$ is not a prime, so this is still not in violation of this result.

Comment: In the polynomial ring, instead of "smaller factors" we look for "lower degree polynomial factors".

Comment: I will write $\Bbb F_p$ for the field with $p$ elements. (This is $\cong \Bbb Z/p$. The notation $\Bbb Z_p$ is still used in some countries in the school, but it leads on this site to confusions.) Then there is an algorithm of division with rest for polynomials in $\Bbb F_p[x]$ (when the "quotient" is $\ne 0$), which leads similarly to the situation in $\Bbb Z$ to the construction of the gcd and lcm of two polynomials. From here, the UFD property follows.

Comment: Euclid’s algorithm

Comment: Either it's $\Bbb F_p$ or $\Bbb Z_p$, the polynomial ring over a UFD is again a UFD.